# Examples of questions which would be roomba-ed if it weren't for the 'has 1 or 0 comments' requirement, which have important answers in the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Continuing from [Modify the 'has 1 or 0 comments' requirement for 'RemoveAbandonedQuestions' script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322197/modify-the-has-1-or-0-comments-requirement-for-removeabandonedquestions-scri)

> Nah. The logic (fear) is that the comments contain the answer.
> <sub>[Catija ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322197/modify-the-has-1-or-0-comments-requirement-for-removeabandonedquestions-scri#comment1151126_343670)</sub>

So let's investigate.  *Would we lose anything important?*

**Question**: What are some examples of questions which would be roomba-ed if it weren't for the 'has 1 or 0 comments' requirement, which have important answers in the comments?

I modified a [a Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1196606/the-roomba-365-day-rule-what-happens-if-we-drop-the-has-1-or-0-comments-requi), and went through many such questions for Stack Overflow.  One thing is clear... answers-in-comments are quite hard to find.  (Although I'm not a Stack Overflow expert.)

I've now checked at least 100 such questions (over various years), and closest I've found thus far:

- [Flyway.migrate not working in idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047122/flyway-migrate-not-working-in-idea):

  > **OP**: ... [the issue has beem resolved. Turns out ths project needed to be imported as a gradle project in idea FIRST, then gradle idea is run.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047122/flyway-migrate-not-working-in-idea#comment83404104_48047122) ...
- [Sublime Text, Python: Interactive shell (when running build) doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046972/sublime-text-python-interactive-shell-when-running-build-doesnt-work) [duplicate]

  > [The specific answer to your question is that you can't do what you want; when you run a program from within Sublime, the stdin of the running process is not connected to anything, so you can't pass it input. You need to run what you're doing externally or use something like SublimeREPL to simulate what you're trying to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046972/sublime-text-python-interactive-shell-when-running-build-doesnt-work#comment83066032_48046972)
- [Marker dragging and do not changing lat lng position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865339/marker-dragging-and-do-not-changing-lat-lng-position)

  > **OP**: ... [Yesterday has my first contact with GMLib, and to start (the demos is for a high Delphi version than mine so I can't use them) I found a tutorial where the instructions tell me to change the property IntervalEvents of the Map Component to 0, and on the event AfterPageLoaded put the code GMMap1.DoMap. But now in you demo I see and understand this properties and so "First" parameter of the Event to avoid reloads of the map.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865339/marker-dragging-and-do-not-changing-lat-lng-position#comment31315889_20865339) ...

I'm not even sure if these count at answers (which is probably why they're comments).

---

#### MathOverflow

- [Are the Fourier coefficients of a new form real](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154086/are-the-fourier-coefficients-of-a-new-form-real)

  > [Yes. The form f¯ is also a new form with the same Hecke eigenvalues at almost every prime p by your argument, so they are equal by the strong multiplicity one theorem.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154086/are-the-fourier-coefficients-of-a-new-form-real#comment395011_154086)

### Theoretical Computer Science

- [Most efficient algorithm to search an unsorted array with a very precise data structure](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/most-efficient-algorithm-to-search-an-unsorted-array-with-a-very-precise-data-st)

  > [Search can take Ω(n) time. Consider the array with (n/2)−1 0's, (n/2) 2's and one 1. In the worst case, in every split, there is least a 0 and a 2 in each part. Only at the bottom split you can figure out where the 1 is.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/most-efficient-algorithm-to-search-an-unsorted-array-with-a-very-precise-data-st#comment58948_22184)

Answer (score 7):

If a community has not curated any valuable content from comments on a post to a point where it can be found in a question or answer within about a year of it being posted, then I think we should assume that its curation may never happen.

In that event, rather than continuing to hope that everything important has been wrung from a comment trail, and/or continuing to worry that it might not have been, then after a year without activity, I think we should assume that even if something "valuable" was lost, then the clean slate that the Roomba creates may provide opportunity for a new and more productive Q&A that is not strung out in a comment trail.

Comment: It looks like (a) most comments are [a year later] unimportant, and definitely not answers [varies from site to site], and (b) answers in comments on 0/1-score questions occur *because* the question and/or answer is poor.  Nevertheless, there may be exceptions where we'd agree that "deleting those comments would be a real loss".  I agree the "it can be re-asked and re-answered" logic applies (if anyone remains interested a year later), but it'd still be nice to have a concrete example.

Comment: My focus is on the content of posts. My enthusiasm to mine comments for an occasional glimmer is non-existent.

Comment: Comments and answers are not the only texts that might have value. The questions themselves have value (if not they should be downvoted), and removing questions of score 0 or higher often results in losing value.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt there’s no suggestion in my answer (or this Q&A) that upvoted questions should ever be Roomba-ed.

Comment: @PolyGeo From my understanding, following your answer would result in the deletion of  questions of score 0.

Comment: Are you talking about nett 0?  If so, then I should clarify that by upvoted I mean nett upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

At [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com) we answer in comments all the time. See [Why do people answer in comments?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments) for some (slightly outdated) background. There is more or less a policy of 'if the answer is a one-liner it can be a comment'. It may be questioned if this is a good idea or not, however fact is that a lot of solutions would get lost if all such questions are removed.

Examples from one year old questions:

February 13, 2019

- [Incompatibility of 'subcaption' package with [hebrew]{babel}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474705/incompatibility-of-subcaption-package-with-hebrewbabel)
  (score 0, no answers, 28 views, 3 comments, answer in 2nd comment)
- [Wrapfigure doesn't stop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474680/wrapfigure-doesnt-stop)
  (score 0, no answers, 34 views, 2 comments, answer in 1st comment)
- [Fitting two pages into one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474678/fitting-two-pages-into-one)
  (score 0, no answers, 36 views, 2 comments, each containing an
  answer)

February 12, 2019

- [Partial compilation of part of a document without breaking the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474601/partial-compilation-of-part-of-a-document-without-breaking-the-page)
  (score 0, no answers, 29 views, 1 comment containing the answer 'this
  is not possible')
- [Glossaries and Index are not Printed at the end of document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474558/glossaries-and-index-are-not-printed-at-the-end-of-document)
  (score 0, no answers, 43 views, 11 comments containing a trouble
  shooting sequence which collectively answers the question)
- [How to remove spacing above subsubsection in Latex? Titlesec not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474469/how-to-remove-spacing-above-subsubsection-in-latex-titlesec-not-working)
  (score 0, no answers, 22 views, 1 comment saying 'this class is not
  intended for this purpose', which is the correct answer)
- [minipar Package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474392/minipar-package) (score
  0, no answers, 55 views, 6 comments, answer in 3rd comment)

This is just two days, there are hundreds of questions like this (and probably more than 'hundreds', it's difficult to guess but there are 14,481 unanswered questions at TeX.SE of which a significant amount is answered in comments).

Comment: If I read the question you link, as to the why of this habbit, nothing of value would be lost if these questions get deleted.

Comment: It seems like it's best to ask to find out.  So I did: [If the 365-day roomba requirement 'has 1 or 0 comments' were dropped, would valuable contributions be lost?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8484/if-the-365-day-roomba-requirement-has-1-or-0-comments-were-dropped-would-valu)

Comment: @Luuklag the questions themselves have value.

Comment: if commenter didn't bother to vote question up it indeed seems low value (because as you wrote they gave answer, they must be in best position to evaluate question content)

Comment: @gnat questions with an answer in comments are usually not very bad (i.e., they are not delete-worthy) but usually not very good either, therefore they don't get any upvotes (at TeX.SE, but I expect also on other sites).

Answer (score -2):

To answer the core of your question:

> So let's investigate. Would we lose anything important?

Yes, removing the "has 1 or 0 comments" criterion would result in losing many perfectly on-topic questions, thereby losing a lot of important content. Plenty of good questions have a score of 0, especially on Stack Exchange websites with low frequentation and for advanced questions (not to mention truly expert questions). I've had hundreds of my questions removed by the auto-deletion script, and the vast majority of them had a score of 0.

---

Here are some examples of questions that got automatically removed because they had a score of 0 (but which I later reposted):

- [How can I know to which class each score corresponds to in LibShortText prediction output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59023318/395857)
- [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository in GitHub for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56812927/395857)
- [Does reducing the amount of carb intake increase the anti-inflammatory effect of turmeric curcumin?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/3871/43)
- [How can I see the network up/down speed for each tab in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/q/1504103/116475)
- [Is there any downside in combining the ingestion of NR and NMN supplements to increase one's level of NAD+?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/18931/43)
- [What is the correlation between the convex acromion type and rotator cuff tears?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/19680/43)

Comment: perfectly on topic questions should be salvaged from roomba by voting up, not by randomly sprinkled comments

Comment: @gnat As you can see in the examples I gave, in practice plenty of perfectly on-topic questions don't receive any vote. Do you want to remove these questions?

Comment: Interesting that all your examples that have answers where answered less than a week after you asked them. Maybe the roomba was what actually was needed to give new life to the question. Remember, most questions that fall off /new|/active are never seen again, which is why the first hours are critical for the question to be answered.

Comment: @Braiam in that case questions should be bumped, not dumped

Comment: Well, community do bump questions. Maybe you should propose that the criteria for bumping should be tweaked.

Comment: @Braiam I don't have any strong preference regarding bump. I do believe dumping is highly disrespectful and should only be reserved for garbage.